# What are the process and practices of requesting for pre-submission peer review from field experts?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I am an undergraduate student in the field of computer science, researching on my own. I have completed writing a paper for my recent research project and all set to submit it to a relevant conference. Since I worked on the paper and project by myself, I am a bit unsure about some parts of the paper, technical as well as presentational.

In my faculty, no one works on this topic so I am left a bit alone on the entire process, including reviewing the paper before sending it to peer review. Is there a practice in academia where I can send some other professor, not affiliated with my work asking help with the paper and some feedbacks on it, sort of a pre-submission peer review?

Is it a good practice? And what would be a good way to do so, if it is done?

Comment: Just be careful with opportunistic authorship predators. There are so many nowadays...

Comment: hi @Scientist can you explain a situation of opportunistic authorship ? In my situation I am also seeking for experts who may want to co-author with a role of reviewer. I am also looking for venues to cover publication costs, so if a researcher might want to cover that in exchance of revising the work miniminally, e.g. dos and don'ts (I would do the work) , it will be ok for me. Tips are welcome. What is the worst opportunitistic scenario that could happen?

Answer (score 7):

If you are an undergraduate and this is most likely one of your first papers, then yes, it is a good idea to have someone check it.

Even if none of the professors or colleagues you work with are familiar with your specific topic, they might still be able to give you advice regarding style and dos and don'ts in your field.

I would suggest to ask around, ask your advisor, ask others from your lab. That should have a higher chance to succeed than contacting a random professor who doesn't know you; they tend to focus their energy more on their own students.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's my third paper, with 2 of them already getting published. This paper is a bit domain critical, so I'm in dire need of help from someone, not in terms of writing it, but at least giving some pointers on what's correct and maybe what's not.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, congratulations on already having two papers published before even finishing your undergrad; that is not common at all! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, getting feedback from experts is a good idea.  But there is no standard process for soliciting that feedback.  Most people you ask for feedback will not provide it.  Even journal editors have a hard time finding formal peer reviewers.